# What are the reasons to use nested returns in javascirpt and how do they work?

Tags: javascript

How does nested return in javascript work? I have tried to find answer in the good internet but find very few sites/examples and still the concept is unclear. What happens when the first return is reached and then the second return?

```
    function getSelected(empid) {
        let utils = myCompany.Xrm.Utils;

        let cleanid = utils.cleanGuid(empid);
        let fetchXml = [
            '<fetch >',
            .....
            .....
            .....
            .....
            '</fetch>',
        ].join('');

        let com = myCompany.Xrm.Common;
        // ** here:
        return com.ExecuteFetch(fetchXml, 'entity', true).then(function(result) {
            let selected = [];
            result.forEach(function(interesting_topic) {
                let id = interesting_topic.id;
                selected.push(id);
            });
            // ** and here:
            return selected; 
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These aren't "nested returns", they each return from a different function.

The first one returns the result of `com.ExecuteFetch()`, which is a `Promise`.  So the `getSelected()` function returns a `Promise`.  At that point, that function is done.  It has returned its value.

At some later time, when the `Promise` is resolved, anything which observes that result will see that the resolution of that promise returns whatever is in `selected`.  So for example, if calling code does this:

```
let result = await getSelected(someValue);
console.log(result);
```

Then `result` will be the returned value from `selected`.  Or if `await` is not an option in that context, you can use the same `.then()` structure shown in the code you have:

```
getSelected(someValue).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

In both cases, `getSelected()` returned a `Promise`, and the callback function which resolves the promise returned a value.  Different functions, different returns.